# iTetxtSharp do not add text to document

Tags: c#, itext

i have some weird issue with iTextSharp.
This is the code

```
for (int j = 0; j < project.Slides[i].Labels.Count(); j++)
{
    string pageContext = project.Slides[i].Labels[j].Text;
    Response.Write(pageContext);
    Response.Write("<br/>");
    //string pageContext = "Some text";

    paragraph = new Paragraph(pageContext,
        FontFactory.GetFont("Verdana", 20));
    doc.Add(paragraph);
}
```

in the for statement: the first line (string...) is work and get the string from list. the 2-3 lines working great, i can see the text of the string in browser. and the last paragraph not working. i see empty pages with no text. When i comment the first string and use the second one (Some text), is working and save the text. any idea??

Comment: The code sample is too small to provide an answer. The problem can't be reproduced. Provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) and I will remove my down-vote. My guess is that after 2 or 3 lines, `pageContext` consists of whitespace. The fact that your code works when you provide `"Some text"`, tells me that you have a *Garbage In, Garbage Out* problem. Maybe `pageContent` is in the wrong encoding. As I said: there simply isn't enough information to provide an answer.

Comment: Also: are you sure that `"Verdana"` is used? I don't see you registering the font to the `FontFactory` anywhere. If `"Verdana"` isn't registered, Helvetica will be used instead. Helvetica is a single-byte font (only 256 characters possible), which in this case means that all non-ASCII characters won't be rendered.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Thanks. Its a encoding issue. thanks :-) my text in hebrew

Comment: Hebrew requires that you define the correct encoding `IDENTITY-H` and a font that supports Hebrew. You also have to define RTL. You are using an old version of iText in which RTL is only supported in `ColumnText` and `PdfPTAble`. If you use iText 7 in combination with the pdfCalligraph add-on, iText can detect the language, and the writing system will automatically be changed to RTL.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Hi thanks for reply, do you have some example how to set the pdfCalligraph?

Comment: Take a look at the [white paper](http://developers.itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/attachments/Whitepaper_pdfCalligraph_2017.pdf). The examples are in the last part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer by @BrunoLowagie

```
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(Server.MapPath("~/StudioFonts/EFT_Beigale Heavy.ttf"),
BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
Font EFT_Beigale_Heavy = new Font(bf, 40);

ColumnText column = new ColumnText(writer.DirectContent);
column.SetSimpleColumn(20, 200, 300, 36);
column.RunDirection = PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL;
column.AddElement(new Paragraph(pageContext, EFT_Beigale_Heavy));
column.Go();
```